# Django passing a value through a ListView

Tags: django, listview

I have the listview working, and I tested a def in the shell, so now I'm tring to pass the returned result from the def through the listview so I can display the value in the html. So the problem is, how to do this?

Here is the def, it is passing some raw sql which compares two tables in two different schemas to show the user how many records need updating.

```
def count_new_rows():
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("""
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM samples.samples a
        FULL OUTER JOIN kap.sample b
        ON a.area_easting = b.area_easting AND a.area_northing = b.area_northing AND a.sample_number = b.sample_number AND a.context_number = b.context_number
        WHERE
        (a.area_easting IS  NULL AND a.area_northing IS  NULL AND a.sample_number IS   NULL AND a.context_number IS  NULL)
        OR
        (b.area_easting IS  NULL AND b.area_northing IS  NULL AND b.sample_number IS  NULL AND b.context_number IS  NULL)
        """)
        count = cursor.fetchall()

        return count
```

And here is the functioning listview

```
class SampleListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'sample/sample_list.html'
    model = Sample
    paginate_by = 50
    queryset = Sample.objects.filter(sample_type='Organic')
```

Do I add the following? If so how do I access the `data` on the html side?

```
    data = count_new_rows()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are probably are looking for `get_context_data()`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data

```py
def get_context_data(**kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    context['new_rows'] = count_new_rows()

    return context
```

Then in a your template, you can do something like:

```html
<div>
     <b>New Rows:</b> {{ new_rows }}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a solution to getting this value in the html? Is it simply `{{ context }}` ?

Comment: Added template example.

Comment: I'm getting `Exception Value: 
get_context_data() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` Any ideas, I'll look closer at my code. I'll check my urls.

Comment: I've put my code here so it is easier to understand, thanks for the help: https://dpaste.de/UrHG

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Django's generic views much. The signature for ListView looks like this: ``def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):``. Try matching the signature in your view with this.

Comment: Actually, ``def get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)`` should suffice.